# RequestDispatcher to url in a different web app

Tags: jsp, servlets

How can i use `RequestDispatcher` to an outher web app in the same work space

in the 1st web app i use it like that

```
 RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("vote.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

can i replace `vote.jsp` with

this url :

`http://localhost:8080/SpeedyServiceClient/JSP/Search/indexS.jsp`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to forward to a different web app in the same tomcat instance, you can:

- in its `META-INF/context.xml` set `<Context crossContext="true" />`
- [`getServletContext().getContext("/app").getRequestDispatcher("f.jsp").forward(..);`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29), where `app` is the name of the other application.

Comment: Which "context.xml" to edit? The one forwarding _from_ or _to_? Both?

Comment: I don't know if this will solve my issue or not, but +1 for being totally awesome.

Comment: You only need to add crossContext property in the context.xml of the 'from' web app.

Comment: If you want to forward request to another web application then you need to put the context app of that application **without** leading slash, because **If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root**.  I.e.you have to write `getServletContext().getContext("app").getRequestDispatcher("f.jsp").forward(..);` where `app` is the name of the other application.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to a different server/servlet context, it would be more typical to go ...

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SpeedyServiceClient/JSP/Search/indexS.jsp");
```

Comment: no sir i cant use this url , cur the url with down vote accept
 

If you are going to a different server/servlet context, it would be more typical to go ...

response.sendRedirec will be /Path of 1st app/http://localhost:8080/SpeedyServiceClient/JSP/Search/indexS.jsp so thats dont work

Comment: Hmmm looks like your comment got all garbled -- can you edit it so i can take a look?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553877/can-i-redirect-in-jsp-between-2-web-app i will delete this one look to my 2nd question

Answer (score 3):

From [ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) Javadoc:

> The pathname specified may be relative, although it **cannot extend outside the current servlet context. If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root**. This method returns null if the servlet container cannot return a RequestDispatcher.

What you are looking for is probably a redirect (see [HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) and *Sai* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552231/requestdispatcher-to-url/6552276#6552276)) rather than request forwarding. Keep in mind though that this will send new location to the browser (visible to the user in the address bar) which will load new page as if it was typed by the user.

Comment: yes sir i'm looking for redirect how can i do it to 2nd web app in the same work space ??

Comment: Yes that's true and in order to **forward** request to another context one needs to use context path **without** leading slash as described in my comment under http://stackoverflow.com/a/6555794/999367