# can i redirect in jsp between 2 web app?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, redirect

Hello i have 2 web app in the same worke space
How can i redirect from page in the 1st webb app to the 2nd web app  ?

in one webb app i use :

```
 RequestDispatcher req =request.getRequestDispatcher("vote.jsp");
req.forward(request, response);
```

i want redirect if the session is not open so i can't use that

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/test/"/>
```

i need some thing like the `RequestDispatcher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend do like that :

```
{out.println("Si votre navigateur ne support pas la redirection automatique <a href='http://localhost:8080/HiberBarti/JSP/session/index.jsp'> Click Ic</a>");

String url ="http://localhost:8080/HiberBarti/JSP/session/index.jsp";
//encodeRedirectURL(url);
//sendRedirect(url);
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(url));
}
```