# RequestDispatcher to transfer request to another web app on same server

Tags: jsp, servlets

Is it possible to send http post back request by request dispatcher to a servlet in a different project. I tried but

the given url is checked in same project and gives 404 error...

```
HTTP Status 404 - /FilterI/http:/IP:8080/FilterII/RequestServlet

type Status report

message /FilterI/http:/IP:8080/FilterII/RequestServlet

description The requested resource (/FilterI/http:/10.49.11.197:8080/FilterII/RequestServlet) is not available.
```

Both the wars are deployed on the same server.I can achieve the same thing by using .sendRedirect() function..However why is it not running with the help of requestdispatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> The pathname specified may be relative, although **it cannot extend
>   outside the current servlet context**.

(emphasis mine)

So, what you're asking is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) API. You can get the servlet context of the other application using `ServletContext.getContext("othercontext")` and get request dispatcher of the servlet within that application.

*Below is the code explaining how to do this:*

```
ServletContext otherCtx  = currentServletContext.getContext("otherContext");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = otherCtx.getRequestDispatcher("/forwardedPath");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: You forgot to mention one not unimportant fact and also how to configure it: the ability to get other webapp's context is by default *disabled* on most if not all self-respected containers.

Comment: In tomcat one needs for instance to put crossContext="true" into context.xml . http://stackoverflow.com/a/6555794/21499